# Where does the final -ς in genitive feminine singularis -ᾱς/-ης/τῆς come from?

Tags: etymology, genitive, ancient-greek, articles

The declination pattern for the case endings, as well as the article ὁ, ἡ, τό, seems to fairly closely match that of the grammatical endings you find in Latin:

| Case | Latin | Greek | Latin | Greek | Latin | Greek |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NOM | -us | -ος | -a | -α/-η | -um | -ον |
| VOC | -e | -ε | -a | -α/-η | -um | -ον |
| ACC | -um | -ον | -am | -αν/-ην | -um | -ον |
| GEN | -ī | -ου | -ae | -ᾱς/-ης | -ī | -ου |
| DAT | -ō | -ῳ | -ae | -ᾱͅ/-ῃ | -ō | -ῳ |
| ABL | -ō | [—](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5FRVvjGL2C0) | -ā | [—](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5FRVvjGL2C0) | -ō | [—](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5FRVvjGL2C0) |

The -us/-ος similarity is plain to see (and makes perfect sense considering how Old Latin /-os/ was raised to /-us/); the same pattern happened with Old Latin /-om/ > /-um/, and the interchangability of /m/ and /n/ we see in several other languages, such as German -n for accusative, but English or Norwegian -m for the same (*him*/*ham* for instance) is a common pattern in Germanic and Latin languages, as far as I know. Thus we have a place for the accusative -um/-ον|-am/-αν/-ην relationship. The relationship between -ō and -ου/-ῳ are again plain enough to see, as well as -ae/-ᾱͅ/-ῃ (considering the overlapping of the dative and ablative in Latin with the genitive and dative in Greek). The odd one out, it seems, is the -ᾱς/-ης in genitive feminine singularis.

Viewing the etymology of the Greek article on Wiktionary, we are informed that it stems from PIE *só, *séh₂, *tód, almost exactly matching ὁ, ἡ, τό; I would assume the initial s- was muted fairly early on, and the same for the final -d.

I have by way of Latin and German come to expect /-m|-n/ and /-s/ to be signs of an accusative (and verily the /-s/ is exactly what you find in the plural both in Latin and in Greek (though not in German). How did that pesky /s/ end up sneaking its way into the Greek genitive feminine singularis, and not in masculine/neuter?

Comment: Latin has an archaic first-declension genitive *-as*, as seen in *paterfamilias*. Latin's *-ae* is actually the odd one out; it developed by analogy to the second declension's (innovated) *-i* genitive.

Comment: When I saw that the Greek ablative is a YouTube link, I expected precisely that scene from precisely that show. And I was not disappointed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's the other way around, actually: Latin *lost* this *-s*, and Greek retained it! In older Latin, and fossilized phrases like *pater famili**ās*** "father of the household", you see the genitive singular in *-ās*.

The standard explanation I've seen for this change is influence from the second declension (*-us -ī*). The second declension in Latin originally had a nominative plural looking something like *-oi* (as in Greek), and ended up with a similar genitive singular, so by analogy the first declension nom pl *-ai* spread to the gen sg. Later, final *-oi* became *-oe* became *-ī*, as seen in Classical times.

---

P.S. So where did this second-declension genitive singular marker come from?

The predecessor of the genitive singular for the second declension is reconstructed as **-os-yo*, as seen in Sanskrit *-asya*, Homeric Greek *-oio*, and Old Latin *-osio*. In Attic, *-oio* got contracted to *-ou*, as expected. But in Latin, *-osio* got completely displaced by a different form…of unclear origin. So the best we can say is that it happened somewhere in the Old Latin period and we're not sure why.

Answer (score 9):

You have it backwards. The sigma is original. From Sihler 263.7:

> Gen.sg. PIE *-*es*, *-*os*, *-*s* are all attested forms of the gen.sg. marker and all three would yield much the same results in the historically attested IE languages when added to the stem *-*eH<sub>2</sub>-*. Most authorities assume a full grade form, and G ending-accented forms in *-*ᾱς*, Att.-Ion. *-*ης*, are easier to explain if one starts from *-*éH<sub>2</sub>os* (**48**) or *-*éH<sub>2</sub>es*.
>
> The ending is attested unchanged, apart from regular phonetic developments, in InIr., Gmc., Celt., G, and Ital. It is retained in Sab., but in L it occurs only in a few forms in inscriptions and early authors, as MOLTAS 'multae' and Enn. *viās*. But if survived in fossilized phrases, of which *pater familiās* 'head of the household' is doubtless the best known, and also in several adverbs like *aliās* 'at another time/place'.
>
> The usual L ending in -ae is a purely L creation. Its makeup is revealed in its OL manifestations like Plaut. *fīliāī* gen.sg. 'daughter': -*ī* imported from the o-stems (**259.8B) was added to the stem in -ā-.

Comment: Dammit! Just barely too slow again! (But it's good to have multiple answers, and this seems entirely correct; +1)

Comment: @Draconis Beaten, but you were "victorious" in the end. ;)